# Por que usar String em um bloco switch é mais eficiente do que em um bloco if-else?

Tags: java, desempenho, if, switch

De acordo com a [documentação do Java](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/language/strings-switch.html):

> The Java compiler generates generally more efficient bytecode from switch statements that use String objects than from chained if-then-else statements.

Sem contar o fato de que utilizar `.equals()` torna *case-sensitive*, de que forma precisamente este código é mais "eficiente"?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

A principal razão neste caso é que ele não compara as *strings* com `equals()` e sim com `hashCode()`. Depois de compilado cada `case` guardará o *hash* da *string* e não a *string* em si. Aí ele gera o *hash* da variável que está sendo usada no `switch` e compara estes valores inteiros que é muito mais rápido que comparar uma sequência de caracteres (se tiver alguma forma de *cache* do *hash code*, caso contrário pode ser pior).

Assim permite haver um ganho na busca porque o `switch` usa uma tabela de *lookup* ao invés de percorrer cada condição. O `if` é O(n) e o `switch` costuma ser O(1).

*Bytecode* comparado ([retirado dessa resposta no SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10836790/221800)):

```
Compiled from "CompileSwitch.java"
public class CompileSwitch {
  public CompileSwitch();
    Code:
       0: aload_0
       1: invokespecial #8  // Method java/lang/Object."<init>":()V
       4: return

  public static void main(java.lang.String[]);
    Code:
       0: ldc           #16 // String C
       2: astore_1
       3: ldc           #18 // String A
       5: aload_1
       6: invokevirtual #20 // Method java/lang/String.equals:(Ljava/lang/Object;)Z
       9: ifne          28
      12: ldc           #26 // String B
      14: aload_1
      15: invokevirtual #20 // Method java/lang/String.equals:(Ljava/lang/Object;)Z
      18: ifne          28
      21: ldc           #16 // String C
      23: aload_1
      24: invokevirtual #20 // Method java/lang/String.equals:(Ljava/lang/Object;)Z
      27: pop
      28: return
}
```

#### Switch

```
Compiled from "CompileSwitch.java"
public class CompileSwitch {
  public CompileSwitch();
    Code:
       0: aload_0
       1: invokespecial #8 // Method java/lang/Object."<init>":()V
       4: return

  public static void main(java.lang.String[]);
    Code:
       0: ldc           #16 // String C
       2: astore_1
       3: aload_1
       4: dup
       5: astore_2
       6: invokevirtual #18 // Method java/lang/String.hashCode:()I
       9: lookupswitch  { // 3
                    65: 44
                    66: 56
                    67: 68
               default: 77
          }
      44: aload_2
      45: ldc           #24 // String A
      47: invokevirtual #26 // Method java/lang/String.equals:(Ljava/lang/Object;)Z
      50: ifne          77
      53: goto          77
      56: aload_2
      57: ldc           #30 // String B
      59: invokevirtual #26 // Method java/lang/String.equals:(Ljava/lang/Object;)Z
      62: ifne          77
      65: goto          77
      68: aload_2
      69: ldc           #16 // String C
      71: invokevirtual #26 // Method java/lang/String.equals:(Ljava/lang/Object;)Z
      74: ifne          77
      77: return
}
```

Ainda que o código seja maior, ele executa de forma mais rápida por não ter que percorrer todo ele como no anterior.

Note que há uma comparação da *string* para confirmar se não houve colisão do *hash* mas ela é executada só para o caso que deu *hash* igual e não para todas condições.

Obviamente que a diferença fica mais perceptível quando há vários `case`s. Com poucos pode até haver perda de performance. E claro que isto vai depender também da ordem do que precisa ser achado. Se o primeiro `if` satisfizer a condição é provavelmente mais rápido que o `switch` (não garanto porque depende de implementação).

Outro motivo que **pode** fazer o `if` ser mais rápido é se a *string* for muito curta. Uma comparação direta acaba sendo mais rápida que ter que gerar o *hash* para depois comparar seu resultado.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Java/Conceptual.md).