# Como fazer um switch em C#?

Tags: c#, .net, estilo-de-codificação, switch

Vejo muitas pessoas dizendo que é errado fazer `switch` no código, pois acaba pesando e é feio.

É correto a maneira que eu estou usando e qual seria uma alternativa ao uso dele? Encher o código de `if`/`else`?

```
      int TipoOsFiltrada = 0;

      switch (TipoOsFiltrada)
      {
        case 0:
          field = "nome";
          fieldValue = "'" + usuarioLogado.NOME + "'";
          break;
        case 1:
          field = "codcar";
          fieldValue = codCar.ToString();
          break;
        case 2:
          field = "codset";
          fieldValue = codSet.ToString();
          break;
        default:
          field = "nome";
          fieldValue = "'" + usuarioLogado.NOME + "'";
          break;
      }
```

Comment: Depende muito da situação, o swtich case pode ser muito bom em determinados casos, conforme a própria documentação já explica "A instrução switch geralmente é usada como uma alternativa para um constructo if-else se uma única expressão é testada com três ou mais condições. Por exemplo, a instrução switch a seguir determina se uma variável do tipo Color tem um dos três valores:" [documentação](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/switch)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Vejo muitas pessoas dizendo que é errado fazer `switch` no código, pois acaba pesando e é feio

Não vejo isso. Pode ser que eu use bons programadores como referência :)

`switch` é elegante e rápido, por isso toda linguagem moderna, como as antigas, possuem ele. Sabendo usar ele é muito poderoso e facilita bastante, além de ser mais rápido que outras opções na maioria dos cenários. De fato ele existe por otimização de execução em primeiro lugar, e elegância em segundo, portanto não consigo imaginar de onde surge essas ideias.

Bom, até imagino em outro cenário. Existem umas pessoas que falam isso porque porque é menos orientado a objeto. Mas se você perguntar porque é ruim, em geral elas não sabem dizer, leram em algum lugar e ficam repetindo. Elas não dão contexto, como ocorre com quem tem entendimento incompleto das coisas (algo que você está buscando se livrar aqui). Claro que em algum contexto não é tão adequado usá-lo, mas isto vale para todos os recursos da linguagem de programação, sem exceção, vale para variáveis, literais, operadores, todos os comandos, até um simples ponto e vírgula.

Se a comparação é com `if` eu diria que ele costuma ser mais elegante nos casos onde ele pode ser usado (nem todos ele pode). O caso mostrado na pergunta é bem básico e o mais ideal para sua adoção. Ele fica mais rápido e mais bonito, ainda que bonito seja algo subjetivo (seria mais se não fosse obrigado usar `break`).

Claro que considerando a primeira linha, ele nem faz sentido porque é garantido que só o primeiro será executado.

Tem uma pergunta que fala mais sobre o funcionamento dele: [Como funciona o switch por baixo dos panos?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/176675/101) (apesar de ser outra linguagem, funciona igual)

Também pode ser útil ler:

- [Qual a diferença entre Switch, Case e If, Else?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/58192/101)
- [Por que usar String em um bloco switch é mais eficiente do que em um bloco if-else?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/82667/101)
- [Usando Switch Case para intervalos](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/258024/101)

Nem falei no seu uso como [*pattern matching*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/137912/101) que é muito mais poderoso e interessante, e está disponível no C#, apesar de muitos não saberem disto. E na versão 8 poderá ser usado como [expressão](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/168177/101).

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Conceptual.md).

Comment: Pesado "Não vejo isto. Pode ser que eu use bons programadores como referência :)" kkkkk Mas obrigado!

Answer (score 4):

A Questão do uso do Switch/Case não pode ser pautada entre deixar o código bonito ou feio, mas sim se é válido ou não.

Vejo switch/case sendo comumente usado para fazer a atribuição de variáveis de ambiente por exemplo. Seu exemplo de código se encaixa nessa premissa pois trata de um filtro pré estipulado.